# java.lang.NullPointerException for JSAPI Speech Recognizer in Java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, jsapi

While I tried the simple Speech Recognizer JSAPI (JSR 113) from [here](http://jsapi.sourceforge.net) (this link does not work now) or [here](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr113/index.html) following the examples of that library, I got java.lang.NullPointerException. The error was caused by the line "rec.allocate();". Why did it occur since the recognizer is assigned a line above ("rec = (Recognizer) EngineManager.createEngine(mode);")?

The code is below:

```
import javax.speech.*;
import javax.speech.recognition.*;
...    
static Recognizer rec;
    ...
public static void run(String[] args) {
            try {
                RecognizerMode mode = new RecognizerMode(new SpeechLocale("en", "GB"));
                rec = (Recognizer) EngineManager.createEngine(mode);

                // Start up the recognizer
                rec.allocate();

                // Load the grammar, and enable it
                String grammarMarkup = 
                    "<grammar root='sentence' xml:lang='en' version='1.0' " +
                                 "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar'>" + 
                      "<rule id='sentence' scope='public'>" +
                        "<one-of>" +
                          "<item> hello world </item>" +
                          "<item> good morning </item>" +
                          "<item> hello mighty computer </item>" +
                        "</one-of>" +
                      "</rule>" +
                    "</grammar>";
                rec.getGrammarManager().loadGrammar("grammar:STT", null, grammarMarkup);

                // Add the listener to get results
                rec.addResultListener((ResultListener) new STT());

                // Request focus and start listening
                rec.requestFocus();
                rec.resume();

                rec.waitEngineState(Engine.DEALLOCATED); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You havn't registered your engine.

Comment: Take a look at [EngineManager](http://alfabetiza.freevar.com/java/jsapi2_0_6/javax/speech/EngineManager.html). See if it helps.

Comment: Probably u can be right, but then I just need to add "EngineManager.class.getResourceAsStream("speech.properties")"?

Comment: I have never tried this before. Seeing your question, I did some research, and thought that this documentation might help you. So.. And yes, not registering the Engine, and not connecting the resource to the project may be the breaking factor. Its all there in the docs.

Comment: I tried "EngineManager.registerEngineListFactory("org.jvoicexml.jsapi2.mac.MacEngineListFactory");", but got "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/speech/JavaSpeechSecurity".